# Unable to convert this Pascal code to C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pascal

I don't know `Pascal`, that's why I am asking.
 Maybe it's created file and write there something
There is a Pascal code

```
Program WriteFile;
Uses Crt;
Var Dur,ts,tv,n,vers,i : integer;
    X,FileName : String[12];
    f : file of integer;
begin
  ClrScr;
  Write('Variant=');
  Readln(vers);
  Write('Number of works='); 
  Readln(n);
  Str(vers,X);
  FileName:='Shed'+X+'.tab';
  Assign(f,FileName); 
  Rewrite(f);
  For i:=1 to n do
    begin Writeln(i,'-th work:');
    Write('time of beginning=');
    Readln(ts);
    Write('during='); 
    Readln(Dur);
    tv:=ts+Dur;
    Write(f,ts,Dur,tv)
    end;
  Close(f)
end.
```

Comment: What problems did you run into when trying to convert the code?

Comment: If you do not know what the program is doing, why do you want to convert the code? Grab yourself a Pascal compiler and compile it instead.

Comment: Like @DavidArno says, you should know what the code do, then you can convert the code. There are different ways for different languages

Comment: If you know any programming language, it should be quite easy to determine what that code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be something like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear(); //unnecessary
        Console.Write("Variant=");
            int vers = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Number of works=");
            int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string X = vers.ToString();
        string FileName = "Shed" + X + ".tab";
        //or string FileName = "Shed" + vers.ToString() + ".tab"; //without unnecessary X variable

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FileName, string.Empty); //clear file

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName);
        int ts;
        int dur;
        int tv;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "-th work:");
            Console.Write("time of beginning=");
            ts = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("during=");
            dur = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            tv = ts + dur;

            file.WriteLine(ts.ToString() + "\t" + dur.ToString() + "\t" + tv.ToString());
        }

        file.Close();
    }
```